# How Do I Preserve HTML Formatting In MySQL database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-lists

I'd like to store some text in my database that has a couple paragraphs and a couple hyperlinks.

For example, the code will look like this:

```
<p>Welcome to the show. </p>

<p>Here you will find these things: </p>

<ol>
   <li>Thing one</li>
   <li>Thing Two</li>
</ol>

<p>Visit us at <a href="www.google.com">Google.com</a> if you have any questions.
```

Basically I want to store this block of code in a table, and then when I retrieve it be able to echo it out and preserve the formatting. How would I go about doing this? My table is set up as a TEXT field entry.

Comment: Text supports whitespace, so store it as written, and output it as such. The only nuances might be _where_ you output it, and how the medium renders it. But the data will be stored as-is, 'formatting' and all.

Comment: Have you even tried to store and output HTML?

Comment: @JimRomeFan When you say formatting, do you mean the line breaks and the tabs?

Comment: @Justin Why would anyone be using tabs in any kind of development?

Comment: @GrantThomas I don't really understand your question.  Tabs are commonly used to improve readability.  Depending on the purpose, a token of \t is also improves the amount of space used as you aren't storing 3 or 4 spaces, depends how you set yours up.

Comment: @Justin I can't think of a single developer that would recommend tabs over spaces these days; indeed, I thought that was well settled and that any new generations would pick it up as conventional wisdom. Just Google it, tabs in source is a no-no (people do use the tab button, but any good environment and responsible developer has this configured to automatically insert _n_ spaces - a shortcut, if you will).

Comment: @GrantThomas I guess I should clairify, when I said tab the underlying thought was a "tab" is a pre-set number of spaces to be inserted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TEXT is text - in MySQL the contents do not get edited or manipulated in any way. What you put in there will be what you get out, with no changes.

So you're fine - use TEXT.

Comment: what kind of cleaning to we have to do to the input text, so we can check for SQL injection ?